# What rate is nonparametric rate?

Tags: nonparametric, terminology, convergence

In the context of convergence of estimators and such, I occasionally encounter the expression *nonparametric rate*. E.g. Hall & Mitchell ["Recent Developments in Density Forecasting"](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1057/9780230244405_5) (2009) write on p. 217:

> the advantage of the Corradi and Swanson test relative to Hong’s is that it converges at a parametric rather than nonparametric rate

Can one say in any generality what the nonparametric rate is? Is the reader supposed to get anything more out of such a characterization than that the nonparametric rate is slower than parametric? I suppose the rate depends on the dimensionality and other aspects of the problem, but is something more concrete that could be said?

Comment: Googling "nonparametric rate" turns up helpful information, such as Peter Bickel & Ya'acov Ritov, *Nonparametric Estimators Which Can Be "Plugged-In."  The Annals of Statistics 2003 Vol. 31, No. 4, 1033-1053.

Comment: @whuber, thank you. The one I had found was Hall ["On Convergence Rates in Nonparametric Problems"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1403583) (1989). Looked a bit technical, though that is perhaps to be expected given the topic... I wonder if anything useful could be said nontechnically.

Comment: Parametric rate is sometimes used to refer to an estimation/convergence rate of $1/\sqrt{n}$. Nonparametric rates (e.g. of regression functions) are usually substantially slower than $1/\sqrt{n}$. There are a rich class of nonparametric estimands (so-called path wise differentiable) that can be estimated at a rate $1/\sqrt{n}$ (Bickel et al., 1993)